# How to call an asp.net web application via command line?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an internal asp.net web application which users can configure and execute automated tests. I'd like to be able to launch tests with is application but from a remote command line console or other non browser way. The goal is to be able to launch tests without user interaction.
Any ideas how to do this without a high impact on the existing solution?
Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: A command line HTTP client like [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se) ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, I'm not familiar with curl. Could you use it to send commands that login to the web application and run a particular method with parameters?

Comment: It loads urls in the same way that a browser does, you just call one with appropriate post/get parameters & cookies

Comment: Interesting, do ou know of any good curl examples that interest with an asp.net application? I'll google for some myself.

Comment: I once used ikvm to compile HTML unit as a .net assembly.  HTML unit is a headless browser (No UI is rendered to) that is used by Java devs to test web applications.  I found it had pretty good support for automating page posts and finding element values from the response (you could query the results using XPath expressions and activate parts of the page, which was useful if your page uses javascript).  I don't have a step-by-step since I did this years ago, but it is just one type of solution you could use.

Comment: If you are looking for a more powerful solution to test your web application, try [WatiN](http://watin.org).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Just to clarify, I'm trying to call a c# method within an asp.net web application without using a browser. I guess command line or any other way would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was Web API. I found a way to do exactly what I wanted by adding a few simple files to the asp.net application and then calling it using PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod. Details of setting up the Web API: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms
Details of using Invoke-RestMethod: http://csharpening.net/?p=1613
John

Comment: Nice one. although the Invoke Restmethod link is broken, you point in the right direction. Thanks!